# ColdFusion 2018 REST API File Upload with multipart/form-data

Tags: rest, api, coldfusion, postman, coldfusion-2018

How can we upload a file using enctype="multipart/form-data" in a ColdFusion 2018 REST Service?

Mocking up a simple service;

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="file">

   <cffunction name="postUpload" restpath="upload" access="remote" returntype="struct" httpmethod="POST" produces="application/json">

       <cfset var response = {} />  

       <cffile 
          action = "upload"
          filefield = "file"
          destination = "D:\files\temp\"
          accept = "application/pdf"
          nameConflict = "overwrite"
          result="myFile"
        >

        <cfset response = myFile />

        <cfreturn response>
   </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

And I have called it from POSTMAN

path : [APIPATH]/file/upload

httpmethod : POST

### Headers

Content-Type : multipart/form-data

### Body : form-data

```
  key       Type      value
  file      File    : document.pdf (uploaded from POSTMAN)
```

### Response

```
 {
   "message": "Not Found",
   "success": false,
   "errcode": "404"
 }
```

I have tried the Body part without the file uploaded and it gives

```
The form field file did not contain a file. (Error in ColdFusion log file)

{
  "message": "Internal Server Error",
  "success": false,
  "errcode": "500"
}
```

My question is, why it gives 404 error while I am trying it with file uploaded?